# How to click on webtable specific row

Tags: hp-uft

I have this code that clicks on first row and column one just fine.

```
Set oExcptnDetail = Description.Create
oExcptnDetail("micclass").value = "WebElement"
oExcptnDetail("html tag").value = "TD"
Set chobj=Browser("").Page("").WebTable("Code").ChildObjects(oExcptnDetail)
chobj(0).Click
```

How can I click on a specific row using above code?

I used childitem that did not work.

```
set objLink = Browser("bb").Page("bb").WebTable("Name_2").ChildItem(4, 1, "WebElement",0)
```

---

**Update 1**

I tried the below code. It did not click row 3 col 1.

```
Set desc = Description.Create
desc("html tag").value = "TR" 
Set rows = table.ChildObjects(desc)
desc("html tag").value = "TD"
Set cells = rows(3).ChildObjects(desc)
Set TableCell = cells(1)
Browser("").Page("").WebTable(TableCell).Click
```

Comment: Your `set` statement looks fine so long as you are going for row 4, column 1, the element inside the cell at that position is a `WebElement` and you want the first item `UFT` finds matching that requirement.  You just need an `objLink.Click` from the look of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UFT's `ChildItem` function returns elements **contained** within cells, this means that it won't return the `TD` that **is** the cell, only its descendants.

In order to get the cell itself you should use [`WebTable.Cell`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/latest/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Web/WEBPACKAGELib~WebTable.html#Cell), this is a relatively new functionality in UFT and you may not have it. If you don't you should be able to write a helper function like this (note I'm writing this without checking it out, it may need additional work and error handling):

```
Function TableCell(table, nRow, nCol)
    Set desc = Description.Create

    desc("html tag").value = "TR" ' Or "T[RH]" to capture TH too
    Set rows = table.ChildObjects(desc)

    desc("html tag").value = "TD"
    Set cells = rows(nRow).ChildObjects(desc)

    Set TableCell = cells(nCol)
End Function
```

Then you can use [`RegisterUserFunc`](https://www.learnqtp.com/using-registeruserfunc-for-object-method-overriding/) to use it as `WebTable.Cell` if you wish.

Then you can use it thus:

```
TableCell(Browser("").Page("").WebTable("Code"), 4, 1).Click
```

Or if you used `RegisterUserFunc` to register it as `Cell`:

```
Browser("").Page("").WebTable("Code").Cell(4, 1).Click
```

Comment: I did not completely understand. It does not show click. How can I click the cell once I set the cell?

Comment: @bugfinder I've added usage to the answer

Comment: I did not use RegisterUserFunc. It worked for some rows and did not work for other rows. Ex- if row is 6, it works. If row is 9 , it does not work.  I think your code is correct. Something to do with the application. Thanks.